# Python - open file with a path

Tags: python, file, path, window

how can I open a file in Python (windows) by a path and use every line of document for next part of my program?

I tried for ex

```
path = open('C:\\Users\\xoxo\\Desktop\\file.txt', 'r')
print(path)
```

(with one '\' also)

Comment: `for line in open('C:\\Users\\xoxo\\Desktop\\file.txt', 'r'):`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply open a file; you must `read()` it first. You would need to do:

```
path = open('C:\Users\xoxo\Desktop\file.txt', 'r')
print(path.read())
```

This will output whatever you have in `'file.txt'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('C:\Users\xoxo\Desktop\file.txt', 'r') as f:
    a=f.readlines()
for x in a:
    # your code
```

It reads every line(including `\n`) in the file into a list.